# How to do google Sign In with the help of idToken in Django

Tags: python, flutter, google-oauth

This is the code I use to retrieve idToken in my flutter app

```
  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final result = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final ggAuth = await result!.authentication;      
      print(ggAuth.idToken); // this is the one that I use as token value
      print(ggAuth.accessToken);      
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

And this is the code I use to access user info in my backend.

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

try:
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
    userid = idinfo['sub']
    print(userid)

except ValueError:
    print('Invalid token)
```

But after replacing the token variable with the token received from flutter app and replacing the CLIENT_ID with the id generated for my app (available in the console) , it still throws the error of invalid token. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT- When I use https://jwt.io/ to decode the token it works as expected and I get all the details.

Comment: You understand that an id token and an access token are not the same thing.  

Id token is just login or authorization, Access token is authentication and will give you access to user data.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, I am following this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: Yes that is sign-in or Open id connect.  It is not authorization.  Oauth2 and open id connect are not the samething.

Comment: @DaImTo I am sorry the page looks like exactly what I am trying to do. I have my backend in django and frontend with flutter. User taps sign in with google and that send the idToken to my backend which then will use to connect with google and ask for user email and name. Is this not the way to do this?

Comment: You still don't understand the difference.  Try sending the Access token. Id tokens are just for authencation (Login OpenId connect) access tokens are for authorization (Oauth2, consent to access data.).   Even then you are only going to have access to their email if you requested the email scope when authorizing the user,

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the idToken that I had was correct but flutter terminal was not able to print its full length and because of which I was copying only half the token and was getting a signature error when checking manually.

Answer (score 0):

**Authentication** Think of the id token as your birth certificate. It just identifies you as a person.

**Authorization** Think of the access token as your drivers license its what contains the permissions that you have to drive a car.

An Id token does not out write give you permission to access any data on google servers.  With an access token you have been authorized to access some data in this case some  profile information.

The issue you are having is that you are using sign-in in. Sign in is Open id connect think of it as a birth certificate (Id token).  There is a user their who is signing in to your app. They are in fount of their computer.  By default with Google signin gives you get basic profile information.   What you are doing with Jwt.io is checking the claims that are returned in the Id token.  Id tokens are just the token that allows your application to identify that the user is logged in.  There should also be a sub claim there you should use this id to map the user to your integral user system.  There may be a user name and email address in the claims but you can not guarantee that they will be there every time google has stated they do not always return these claims.

To get user profile information after the user has logged in you should be using the people api the people.get method when passed the access token will return to you the profile information of the currently authenticated user.

beyond that you should IMO not be passing tokens to your backend if you want the token in the backend you should log the user in using your backend language.

Comment: Okay so are you saying that I should try this https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python ?. I understood what you said but the confusing part is if this is not the correct way then why does google write this ''Then, on the server, verify the integrity of the ID token and use the user information contained in the token to establish a session or create a new account.'' in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth (the resource that I was using). What is the purpose of this page?

Comment: If you create an application and you want users to be able to signin to your application using their google accounts you would use sign in.      if You have an application with users logged into your system and you just want your users to grant you consent to access their google profile information then you want to use Oauth2.

Comment: And about what I am trying to do is , my app is passwordless so I have two options to sign in. First is use an email address where I will send the otp. Use that otp to sign in (thus verifying that you have access to the email) second is use google/gmail. To prove you are the owner I take your idToken ( which has email in it cuz as said by google ''These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and "email" OAuth scopes to the application.'' which I do.) and I make the account using those details.

Comment: Note: [Pyton quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python) is for an installed / desktop  application if your doing this as a web app it wont work.   [web-server python](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python)

Comment: I want to use sign in as you said, and I am using sign in

Comment: Then we are back to the beginning, please read the first two lines of my answer again.   Google APIs support Oauth2 for Authorization and consent.   Google sign-in is for Authentication.   You can not use an Id token to access google api you need an access token.

Comment: But I want authentication I don't want to use google api. I want and I am doing exactly as said here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth . I have tried sending access token too that does not work either. When I use jwt.io to decode it produces the result that is supposed to be produced and I want that exact information to make the user's account. And it has the name and email address cuz I ask user's permission for that and then move forward. So it will be there everytime I use it as said by google no?

Comment: The way to get user profile information is though the people api.

Comment: I see but then again then what is the purpose of that page then?